# from solidity: ParserError: Expected ',' but got ';'

Tags: solidity, remix, smart-contract-wallets

i'm trying to complie my solidity contract but i'm getting the error below

```
from solidity:
ParserError: Expected ',' but got ';'
  --> contracts/samEsc.sol:50:39:
   |
50 |        totalAmount = (_amount.add(fee);//total amount customer will send
   |                                       ^
```

This is the line of code below

`

```
function pay(address _acToken, uint256 _amount) payable public returns (uint256) {

       fee = (_amount.div(10_000)).mul(feePercentageInBasisPoint);//divide the amount customer is sending by 10,000 and multiplying anser by feepercentage to get the fees
       totalAmount = (_amount.add(fee);//total amount customer will send
       gotokAmount = totalAmount.sub(fee);

       require(IERC20(_acToken).balanceOf(msg.sender) >= totalAmount);
```

`

i'm sure that ';' is how you end a line of code in solidity, why is it expecting ','

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parenthesis;

Instead of:

```
totalAmount = (_amount.add(fee);
```

It should be:

```
totalAmount = (_amount.add(fee));
```

Or:

```
totalAmount = _amount.add(fee);
```